# Approximating derivative of Dirac delta function using mollifiers

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Given $\rho_\epsilon (x)$ a delta approximating sequence, what is the limit in distribution of the function $$\frac{\rho_\epsilon (x) - \rho_\epsilon (x-\epsilon)}{\epsilon} \text{?}$$
Intuitively it should converge to the derivative of the Dirac delta in zero $\delta'_0$, though I'm having trouble showing this rigorously.
I assumed $\rho_\epsilon (x) = \rho(\epsilon x)/\epsilon$ for some mollifier $\rho$.

The book I'm using suggests that I use the fundamental theorem of calculus to represent the derivative of $\rho_\epsilon$ first, though this only makes calculations messier and I can't see how this is supposed to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of doing this is to change variables so that the difference quotient falls on the test function.  (This is a "discrete" version of integration by parts.)  Suppose $\varphi$ is a smooth test function.  Then
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\rho_{\epsilon}(x) - \rho_{\epsilon}(x - \epsilon)}{\epsilon}\right) \varphi(x) \, dx &= - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \rho_{\epsilon}(y) \left(\frac{\varphi(y + \epsilon) - \varphi(y)}{\epsilon} \right) \, dy \\
&= - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \rho_{\epsilon}(y) \varphi'(y_{\epsilon}) \, dy,
\end{align*}
where $y_{\epsilon}$ is a point on the interval between $y$ and $y + \epsilon$.  Send $\epsilon \to 0$ to find 
$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\frac{\rho_{\epsilon}(x) - \rho_{\epsilon}(x - \epsilon)}{\epsilon}\right) \varphi(x) \, dx = - \varphi'(0).$$
This proves that 
$$\frac{\rho_{\epsilon}(\cdot) - \rho_{\epsilon}(\cdot - \epsilon)}{\epsilon} \to \delta_{0}'$$
in the sense of distributions.